# R list of dataframe conserving column and data structure

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe like:

```
colum1  column2   column3    column4
0.34    0.45      4450       21
0.32    0.46      4451       41
0.41    0.12      2150       38
.
.
.
```

This dataframe contains 2000 elements. I would like to create a list of 100 dataframes with randomly selected rows. I have coded a prototype:

```
matrix_sampling<-list()
counter=1
original_data <- a

while( counter < 101) {
 sub_sample <- data.frame(original_data[sample(nrow(original_data), 20), ])
 matrix_sampling <- c(matrix_sampling, sub_sample)
 counter = counter+1
}
```

However when I access to the following matrix:

`matrix_sampling[[1]]` it print 0.34 I was expecting the first dataframe. I really would like a data structure like:

```
matrix_sampling[1] = dataframe1
matrix_sampling[2] = dataframe2
...
```

Where I can even see the column's names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replicate`. In the example below we generate a list with two dataframes, each containing five rows of `iris`. So you would need to adjust this accordingly.

```
n_rows <- 5
samples <- 2

set.seed(1)
out <- replicate(n = samples,
                 expr = iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), size = n_rows),],
                 simplify = FALSE)
out
#[[1]]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
#56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica
#30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa

#[[2]]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica
#141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica
#98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor
#10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
```